# Filling Data In Excel from Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Good afternoon,

I have a list of names in excel and I have a template in Microsoft word.

I would like to fill in a name and information in the word document and for the information to be auto filled in excel next to the name entered.

Apologises I have explained poorly.

Is this possible? Could I please be advised?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your needs are similar to linking excel and word data.

I recommend that you use Mail Merge in word.

Insert merge fields:

Go to Mailings > Address Block.

To add a greeting line, choose Greeting Line.

To add other merge fields, like invoice numbers, see Insert mail merge fields.

Choose OK.

Choose File > Save.

More information:

[Mail merge using an Excel spreadsheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3)